# How to use DialogBoxes in a TabPanel in GWT

Tags: gwt, tabpanel, dialog

i use the GWT `TabPanel` and want to use a `DialogBox` in one of these tabs. I think the `DialogBox` is added to the `RootPanel` because i see the box in every Tab.
Is there a option to see the box only in the box there the panel was created? Or must i create my own DialogBox or overwrite some methods (`.show`?)

Greetz,
Destiny

Answer (score 0):

A `DialogBox` is is a popup and not attached to any of your panels. So you can't use a `Dialogox` ***in*** a `TabPanel` as it will not be attached to that panel as you found out yourself (it's attached to the `RootPanel`). If you want to only show this dialogbox when a specific tab is selected you need to hide the dialog box when another tab is selected. You can do this by adding a `TabListener` on the TabPanel and implement the `onBeforeTabSelected` method and check which tab is selected and hide or show the dialogbox.

Comment: okay, thanks and if i switch back to the tab which have the dialog? Is there a way to overwrite the .show method?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand why you want to override the show method? If you switch (back) to the tab with the dialog box you can call in the onBeforeTabSelected the show of the dialogbox (if the dialog box is notvisible( isShowing == false) .